# my query returns duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hello i have a query that selects products from a database, but for some reason it returns duplicates. The problem is in my joins i guess since in the product table there is no duplicate product. Here is my query:

```
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT 
 p.name,
 p.slug,
 p.id_product,
 p.price,
 pig.image,
 c1.slug as ssubcat,
 c2.slug as subcat,
 c3.slug as cat
FROM
 tbl_products p 
 INNER JOIN tbl_products_to_categories ptoc 
   ON ptoc.id_product = p.id_product 
 INNER JOIN tbl_catalog_categories c1 
   ON ptoc.id_category = c1.id_category 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_catalog_categories c2 
   ON c1.id_parent = c2.id_category 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_catalog_categories c3 
   ON c2.id_parent = c3.id_category 
 INNER JOIN tbl_products_images_gallery pig 
   ON pig.id_product = p.id_product 
WHERE (c1.slug = :slug OR c2.slug = :slug OR c3.slug = :slug )
 AND p.active = 1 
 AND p.quantity = 1 
ORDER BY p.name ASC 
LIMIT $start, $row_limit");
```

Comment: Difficult without the database design. Are there any many-to-one or one-to-many relations we need to know about?

Comment: I would guess that a product could have multiple images and you are selecting all of them.

Comment: any chance displaying the result from the query above?

Comment: you can see it here https://anticariat.umbrellamedia.ro/carti. You can see on the first page that the 15 animaux familiers is duplicate. It only has 1 image

Comment: @maSTArHiAn asked for the result of the query; can you run the query directly against the database and display the first say 30 results?

Comment: If a product is in multiple categories, you'll get a row for every category it's in.

Comment: 15 animaux familiers is in 2 categories: `Carti-in-limba-franceza` and `Botanica,-Biologie,-Zoologie`

Comment: true, and how could i fix my query to get the product only once when the main category is selected? in this example "Carti"

Comment: Can you show us some data please?

Comment: bummer can't see your result. i'm in a restricted internet. maybe if you can upload an image somewhere... my guess would be your left joins caused the duplication.

Comment: Change the joins with the category tables so that they only join with the "main" records

Comment: any join can produce "duplicate" record, since there are more joined tables than used in SELECT clause. Easiest way to debug: instead listing needed columns run SELECT * from the same joins. You will get all columns and there will be some of them which are not duplicate. Those columns you need will be the same but some unneeded will be not. If you will be not able to avoid that condition use SELECT DISTINCT. It is quite not the best solution, but DISTINCT is there for such purpose.

Comment: i could use `group by p.name`, but is it an inefficient query if i do that?